# How to implement fixed div columns inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngfor

I want to implement a design where I have an array of data that are dynamic and I want to render them in only 3 bootstrap columns per row like this:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
  </div

 <div class="col-md-4">
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
  </div

 <div class="col-md-4">
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
   <a>data</a>
  </div

</div>
```

The output should look like this:

[image]

But when I put `*ngFor` on column div like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let d of data">
   <a>{{d.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div
```

it won't give the same result with the first static approach, any help to reproduce dynamic data looping to give the same result?

Comment: Show your result and the data as well

Comment: You are not getting the same result as you are not iterating the row. Try iterating the row also.

Comment: @SruthiVarghese dont mind abount the picture after getting how to approach this i can add the css to customize the view

Comment: @Exterminator my result is like all data look like they are arranged in 3 columns but every single item is rendered is one `<div class="col-md-4><a>{{dynamic name}} </a> `which i don't want!, i want many `<a>`  in  div1, div2,div3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
columns: string[][] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    const itemsInColumn = Math.floor(this.data.length()/3);
    columns[0] = data.slice(0, itemsInColumn);
    columns[1] = data.slice(itemsInColumn, itemsInColumn * 2);
    columns[2] = data.slice(itemsInColumn * 2);
}
```

In template:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let c of columns">
          <a *ngFor="let d of c">{{d}}</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer looks like what i want but i unfortunatly i can't what you are trying to say on  `columns[0],columns[1],columns[2] `

Comment: Just grouped data in array of columns